# Maven deploy using profile

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I want to deploy to a private Maven repository only if there is a defined profile.

Is this possible? And how can I do it?

Comment: Why do you call `mvn deploy` if you do not want to deploy? Why the extra parameter?

Answer (score 1):

put the repository into profile

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <distributionManagement>
       <repository>
           <id>repsy</id>
           <name>My Private Maven Repository on Repsy</name>
           <url>https://repo.repsy.io/mvn/username/reponame</url>
      </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

you can execute :`mvn deploy -P test`,it will use the repo in the test profile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `skip` property described here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#skip

```
mvn deploy -Dmaven.deploy.skip=true
```